# Django/AngularJS Request header field X-Requested-With error

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, angularjs

I'm trying to get movie info using OMDb API but everytime I send a request I get(i'm running a local server)

```
Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

In Django I added

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

And in AngularJS:

```
App.config(['$httpProvider',
    function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

    }
]);
```

AngularJS code:

```
  $http({
        url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Django&apikey=secret ",
        method: "POST",


    }).
    success(function (res) {



        console.log(res);
    })
```

But it doesn't change the problem
Any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't the error self-explanatory? Remove the `X-Requested-With` from headers. The server does not allow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `X-Requested-With` header from headers. You are using CORS and the server does not allow it.

Read more about access control here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS